# Android sqlite return number of rows from query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select, rows

I am trying to build a method to determine if a user exists in an Android sqlite database before inserting, I have tried to build this method to return the number of rows, however If I try a search for like matches like this

```
    String[] columns = new String[] { SCREEN_NAME, NAME, PROFILE_IMAGE_URL,
            USER_ID };
    Cursor c = friendsDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, SCREEN_NAME
            + " LIKE '" + screenName + "%'", null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Integer count= c.getCount();
    c.close();

    return count;
```

I get the number of rows returned no problem however the minute I look for an exact match like this

```
String[] columns = new String[] { SCREEN_NAME, NAME, PROFILE_IMAGE_URL,
            USER_ID };
    Cursor c = friendsDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, SCREEN_NAME
            + " = '" + screenName + "'", null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Integer count= c.getCount();
    c.close();

    return count;
```

I get 0 rows every time no matter if it matches or not, Im not sure if theres something wrong with my SQL or maybe im using the wrong arguments to make the statement, any help would go a long way thanks

Comment: Why are you using LIKE? Your LIKE query is looking for a prefix match, not a full match like `=` will look for. You might be better off adding an appropriate unique constraint on the screen name column and trapping the exception.

Comment: I was using the LIKE as an example of something I got that worked, what I need is the number of rows returned for an exact match, however I cant seem to get that to work in the second example

Comment: Do you have that screen name in your database? Does the screen name inside the database and the one you're querying on only differ in case?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it might work

Using Raw Query

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" where "+SCREEN_NAME+"='" + SCREEN_NAME + "'", null);
mCount.moveToFirst();
int count= mCount.getInt(0);
mCount.close();
```

Or using the same code but differently

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE , columns, SCREEN_NAME=?, new String[] { SCREEN_NAME}, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
Integer count= c.getCount();
c.close();
```